# Spark collect limited sorted list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory, aggregation, collect

I am trying to use spark to create a limited sorted list for data frame however I am not able to think of a fast and a low memory approach.

My data frame consists of three columns two keys ids and a distance column and I want to get list of top n=50 ids close to each of the ids. I tried groupBy followed by collect_list followed by sort_array, followed by UDF to get only IDs and finally passing it via a UDF to take the first n=50 but it is very slow and sometimes getting a memory error.

```
# Sample Data
val dataFrameTest = Seq(
      ("key1", "key2", 1),
      ("key1","key3", 2),
      ("key1", "key5" ,4),
      ("key1", "key6" ,5),
      ("key1","key8" ,6),
      ("key2", "key7" ,3),
      ("key2", "key9" ,4),
      ("key2","key5" ,5)
      ).toDF("id1", "id2", "distance")
```

If limit is 2 want

```
"key1" | ["key2", "key3"]    
"key2" | ["key7", "key8"]
```

current_approach :

```
sorted_df = dataFrameTest.groupBy("key1").agg(collect_list(struct("distance", "id2")).alias("toBeSortedCol")).
withColumn("sortedList", sort_array("toBeSortedCol"))
```

My data is quite large so that's why spark is the only solution. I appreciate any help/guidance.

Comment: Yours is a graph data, may be you can leverage Spark-GraphX for processing this. If the unique number of keys (both key1 and key2 ) are not too high, you can think of converting your dataset to a Distance-Matrix and then process it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix

Answer (score 1):

What about using one of Spark SQL windowing functions for this? Something like

```
scala> val dataFrameTest = Seq(
     |       ("key1", "key2", 1),
     |       ("key1","key3", 2),
     |       ("key1", "key5" ,4),
     |       ("key1", "key6" ,5),
     |       ("key1","key8" ,6),
     |       ("key2", "key7" ,3),
     |       ("key2", "key9" ,4),
     |       ("key2","key5" ,5)
     |       ).toDF("id1", "id2", "distance")
dataFrameTest: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id1: string, id2: string ... 1 more field]

scala> dataFrameTest.createOrReplaceTempView("sampledata")

scala> spark.sql("""
     | select t.id1, collect_list(t.id2) from (
     | select id1, id2, row_number() over (partition by id1 order by distance) as rownum from sampledata
     | )t
     | where t.rownum < 3 group by t.id1
     | """).show(false)
+----+-----------------+
|id1 |collect_list(id2)|
+----+-----------------+
|key1|[key2, key3]     |
|key2|[key7, key9]     |
+----+-----------------+

scala>
```

Just substitute `row_number()` with `rank()` or `dense_rank()` depending on type of result you need.